# retrieving data from internet from application

Tags: android

i am developing an app in which i want to put a spinner of states and it works fine but i wan to check on run time for the state being selected which i can do successfully using onselectedlistener() ,now the problem is,based on the value obtained from the spinner i wan to select the districts coming under that state from internet because storing all the state information in a small database is not feasible
    firstly can we do like that on run time
    if we can do it,then can someone explain me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the internet permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And then you can simply use a http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: can u just say how to use a intent to search data in specific site?

Comment: It's explained on the site I linked.